# Character deforming with rigging and adding automatic weights

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, weight-painting, inverse-kinematics

Im super new to blender so.. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I added some bones and IK and every time I add automatic weights his body gets all twisted and deformed and distorted. I tried a bunch of things and googled a whole lot but I still can't figure it out... I'd really appreciate some help so I can rig a character properly in the future. Thanks!!!! :)
Here is the file: 
http://www.filedropper.com/characterforz

Comment: Welcome. The best thing, being new to blender, is to follow a basic rigging tutorial. Automatic weights are nice, but good rigging often needs a lot of tweaking of weights, settings... since you googled a lot, are you following one? which? It's easier to support you if people can follow what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 1):

Select the armature, go to pose mode, select all bones, Ctrl A: "Apply pose as rest pose". Then you can parent your mesh to the armature. It's a good habit to apply rotation and scale (Ctrl A) to both mesh and armature also. You will have to tweak the pole angle of your IK leg ion order to get the right deforming direction of the legs. Search for Nathan Vegdahl free rigging course for advanced rigging techinques.